# How do I remove the properties from left panel to hide coordinates so that they do not display in google earth? How do I do that in my kml file?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I would like to ask please how should I amend my kml file so that I can hide the properties that when the name is right clicked, the properties do not appear as they display the coordinates, which I would like to hide.